# GADBannerView pushes UI elements from scrollview when hiding on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, admob

I've been working on a mobile application for iOS platform. I was trying to put an ad banner in my app while I faced something ... I'd say strange.
I have a master-detail view workflow when the user selects an element from the master view detailed information is presented in a new view. The detail view is longer than the display so I've put a UIScrollView element that wraps all other elements - labels, text view and image.
The ad banner is placed out of the scroll view at the bottom of the screen so it is always on screen to the user.
[image: Detail View with UI elements in a scroll view]
So here goes my problem -
 1. I scroll down the view
 2. I click on the ad banner
 3. I close the ad banner view hitting the `Done` button
Now all UI elements inside the scroll view had moved up (check the scrollbar on next images)
[image: UI elements had moved up]
[image: UI elements in the scroll view had moved up]

I've been trying to locate the problem debugging the `GADBannerViewDelegate` method and I've found that in
`- (void)adViewWillDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)bannerView`
everything is just fine and when the next method
 `- (void)adViewDidDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)bannerView`
is fired the UI elements had moved by a couple of hundred pixels up.

I hope I've been clear enough. Should I provide some source code?

P.P. This works the same way on the simulator and on my iPod touch 4th gen
**Deployment Target** of the project is 6.1
I use **GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS** version 6.4.2

Comment: Are you doing anything in viewWillAppear? or any logic when the modal view of the ad is dismissed?

Comment: Hello @RajPara, sorry for my delayed answer. I start to believe that my issue is in the way I use Autolayout - I've created a new project with a scroll view and a GABanner view and got the same issue.